# Android canvas.draw leaks graphic memory

Tags: android, canvas, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I've have a custom view which overrides onDraw and I've noticed that Graphics memory keeps increasing overtime, until my app crashes with OOM (it ranges anywhere from 4h to 12h, based on device).

[image: Graphics]

I'm doing a bit complex drawing but for reproducing purposes, this code does the trick:

```
package com.example.testdrawing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.Random;

public class CustomView extends View {
    private Random rand;
    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        rand = new Random();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        
        // Simulate invalidation loop
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    // I invoke postInvalidate() when the rendering data change.
                    postInvalidate();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // 1) This one leaks memory
        canvas.drawOval(0, 0, 500 + (rand.nextInt(100)), 900 + (rand.nextInt(100)), paint);
        
        // 2) This one keeps graphic memory at constant
        //canvas.drawOval(0, 0, 500, 900, paint);

    }
}
```

Basically, the memory is retained whenever a drawing location is dynamic. If location is static, the memory remains at constant. In both cases, the graphic memory doesn't go down. Here is the profiler output after ~12 minutes for the CustomView:
[image: profiler]

Full sample [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq1pm15qkro3b86/testDrawingSample.zip?dl=0)

EDIT(@PerracoLabs): I don't believe that Random is the culprit. This reproduces by just drawing to dynamic coordinates. I.e:

```
 canvas.drawOval(x++ % 500, y++ % 500, w++ % 1080, h++ % 1000, paint);
```

Also, if these are just allocations stats, why are they accounted into total memory? If not released, it's a leak, right?

It is also strange that memory increase rate is ~100kb regardless of what's drawn.

EDIT 2:

I've attached full sample [app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq1pm15qkro3b86/testDrawingSample.zip?dl=0) that produces this (On Pixel 4, Android 10): [image]

I've stopped profiling since the profiler slowed down to the point it became unusable.
Note that occasional drops where some memory is indeed freed.

Again, to me it doesn't make sense that for few draw calls, the overhead is ~200MB of allocated graphic memory.
I'd really like to understand what's going on here. Obviously, there is a difference when drawing on dynamic locations on the canvas compared when the location is fixed, at which time the memory consumption stabilises.

Comment: Your code has not reason to perform any leaking. A small test to try is to clamp the metrics where you perform nextInt, ensuring the result will be within the canvas bounds, but, I would be surprised it makes any difference. The test would be to find out if it could be a bug at native level with Skia. Can you share more of the other drawing operations you perform?

Comment: @PerracoLabs I've updated the sample code. Basically, including this view into a view hierarchy of the simplest android project reproduces the issue - graphics memory just keeps growing.

Comment: [Do Less, Less Frequently](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view)

Comment: @Yeldar.N Sorry, I don't understand the point. I need to invoke posInvalidate() when my model change to cause UI redraw (it's usually done at 10 fps so it's not much). Also, I don't do any allocations in onDraw().

Comment: Also you can show [rendering performance](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#render)

Answer (score 2):

After testing your code, instead of a memory leak, seems to be allocated memory space which hasn't been reclaimed yet.

In Android the total used memory is the sum of everything including unused resources, and not necessarily resources allocated directly by yourself, these can be allocated by other methods.

Android uses a Garbage Collector to manage memory. The goal of the garbage collector is to ensure that there is enough free memory when it is needed, reclaiming it with minimal CPU overhead, rather than freeing as much memory as possible in one go.

In the test the draw method is being called nonstop, which keeps on allocating memory, but after a threshold it stops allocating anymore. **In such test as it never stops calling the draw method, to be a leak, memory should keep growing always without stopping at any threshold**, and eventually the system would kill the app.

Next a 37 minute screenshot. I took a few captures and overlapped the allocation info panels for better understanding. As you can see the memory growth is the native one, yet after 20 minutes there is no more growth staying at around 60Mb.

[image]

Note that calling explicitly the garbage collector will not free (reclaim) such memory, as [System.gc()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#gc()) only triggers a suggestion and is at the discretion of the system to collect resources, which is basically when the JVM needs memory.

Comment: I don't believe that Random is the culprit. This reproduces by just drawing to dynamic coordinates (ie. use a system time or increment to cover more locations).
Also, if these are just allocations stats, why are they accounted into total memory? If not released, it's a leak, right? It is strange to me that such a simple drawing does so much allocations.

Comment: I have updated the answer as I have been doing more testing, please read again as I rewritten most of it. In addition, I would suggest you perform a new test leaving it running over an hour, but also creating bitmaps or other objects, so actually force memory to grow nonstop. You will see how eventually the garbage collector gets triggered and memory gets reclaimed.

Comment: That's exactly what my original app does. It works with bitmaps up to the point when no more memory is available, at which point it crashes with OOM. If I turn off the drawing to canvas, I see GC invocations which keeps the memory consumption at constant.

Comment: Could you post the OOM stacktrace? It should show the reason. The test code in the question can't produce an OOM at all. I assume you keep on releasing bitmaps when no longer needed with the "recycle()" method. In addition, if you select a range in the memory inspector, it will show the objects which aren't released yet, which will give a better idea of what is being retained. If you could post a sample that produces an OOM would be helpful for further testing.

Comment: I've posted the full sample code for that last stats - I do nothing but drawing overlays.

Comment: Btw I'm trying to produce a sample that leads to OOM. I can't post the original app's code due to privacy concerns.

Comment: are you running on emu or device? I can repro with Pixel 2, Pixel 4 and Samsun S5E tab.

Comment: I was trying with emulators, and were giving 0 graphic allocations, probably the render engine manages it in a different manner, I am now running it in two of my test devices, Huawei Lite P20 and Huawei p30 Pro. Both present memory allocations, yet not growing anymore after a while, P20 stopped at ~60Mb and P30 at ~80mb, already stabilized and not growing anymore. Can't still reproduce an OOM. I will leave them running for a while more.

Comment: I can't reproduce the OOM at all, I hope you post a sample project which reproduces the OOM. As far as I see with the current sample all is as expected, the memory allocated is just not being reclaimed because isn't needed, which is how the garbage collector works. The goal of the garbage collector is to ensure that there is enough free memory when it is needed, reclaiming it with minimal CPU overhead, rather than freeing as much memory as possible in one go or continuously when something is released.

Comment: Yeah, I can not repro OOM in normal conditions. Graphic memory grows up to a point but doesn't crash. I'd like to understand why it can grow that much but I'm limited on time :/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I recently encountered the same problem.

The issue is with the paint object. I haven't tested it with all of the `draw` functions, but when you use a `paint` object with style `STROKE` and using `canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint)` where the `x` and `y` are changed at random - the graphics memory will be increased and never released until an inevitable OOM. This happens on Android 11, but not on Android 7 - haven't tested other versions.

You can easily reproduce it by creating a custom view like so:

```
class OOMLayout: FrameLayout {
    val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.RED
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 4f
    }
    
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        val x = (100..400).random().toFloat()
        val y = (100..400).random().toFloat()
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10f, paint)
        invalidate()
        return
    }
}
```

This will take some time to reach the OOM but the memory leak is clearly visible in the android profiler.
To speed up the memory consumption put the `drawCircle` call inside a loop f.e. a 1000 iterations per `onDraw` - this way the app will OOM in few seconds.

When using paint with style `FILL` - there are no such problems on Android 11.

Comment: Did you find a workaround or fix for this issue? You're describing the exact scenario I need to code and I'm also running out of memory.

Comment: As the last sentence says - I used `FILL` for the paint style. The OOM happened ONLY with `STROKE`.

Comment: To me, it actually seems that paint.strokeWidth is crucial. Just using FILL style doesn't cause memory to grow. Also, I only see this on android 11.

Comment: I've tried building a simple project which reproduces the OOM crash but unsuccessfully; at some point GC starts reclaiming the memory. Still, in my application which is quite complex (uses JNI, external cameras, openGL etc..),if I use paint.strokeWidth, it always crashes with OOM. I if comment out just that one line, it will run for days, so there must be some other factor I can't figure out.

Comment: On Android 12, I don't see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me in compose canvas too.
Using drawPath with a style Stroke and a stroke width > 1 there are memory leaks. With stroke width == 1 It works fine.

In my case the workaround has been using drawPoints with pointMode = PointMode.Polygon instead drawPath. It allows me the desired stroke width with no leaks.